# Use gremlin traversals (Tinkergraph) against the gremlin server

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Is it possible to use Tinkergraph-Gremlin against a local instance of the gremlin-server?
In other words, what's missing from the following source code to make it query the localhost:8182 gremlin-server instead of the in-memory DB:

```
Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a remote traversal.

```
EmptyGraph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
```

Check out the TinkerPop documentation for [Connecting via withRemote()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-remotegraph).